# How do I enable debug on mod_auth_openidc and where is the log file to view it?

Tags: mod-auth-openidc

Hi does anyone know how to enable debug on mod_auth_openidc and where the log file is to view it? I've enabled debug in the httpd.conf file but that doesn't appear to have made any difference to the mod_auth_openidc output in the standard ssl logs.

I've enable debug in apache but it does not appear to have enabled debug output for mod_auth_openidc

Answer (score 0):

change the LogLevel warn to debug in ssl.conf file - restart httpd - mod_auth_openidc debug messages are displayed in the ssl_error_log